# Opening each docx file in a folder and saving as other filetype

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, console

I have a console app that lists docx files in a folder and converts them into another file type (pdf for example).

Here's code:

```
Sub Main()
    For Each arg As String In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
        Select Case Trim(LCase(arg))
            Case "/docx-pdf"
                Dim oWord As Word.Application
                Dim oDoc As Word.Document
                Dim path As String
                Console.WriteLine("Podaj scieżkę folderu:")
                path = Console.ReadLine()
                Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path + "/", "*.docx")
                For Each file As String In files
                    oWord = CreateObject("word.application")
                    oWord.Visible = False
                    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(file, ReadOnly:=True)
                    oDoc.SaveAs(FileName:=file.Replace(".docx", ".pdf"), FileFormat:=Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)
                    oWord.Quit()
                Next
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

My problem is that after converting every file in the folder, the application is trying to open another one that doesn't exist and I'm getting [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbR4p.jpg) error (at least it looks like that).

What did I forget about?

Comment: Could you please translate the error? The best way to find out where it goes wrong is to step through your code using a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting file opening error saying that "the file is probably damaged" most likely because your wildcard `*.docx` is also leading to inclusion of temporary files created by Word whenever DOCX files are open for editing (more specifically here: [KB 211632 – see paragraph Owner File](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211632)) which have file name beginning with tilde and dollar sign (`~$`), e.g. `~$nualReport.docx`. These files contain no document content, but only logon name of person who opened corresponding DOCX file. You are attempting to open these owner files using Microsoft Word what indeed fails.

You have two options how to resolve this:

1. rely on fact that these owner files are actually hidden (that have `h` attrbute set) so get only list of non-hidden DOCX files
2. test each file name before processing and if it begins with `~$`, just use `Continue For` to skip further processing of the file (I recommend this option)

   ```
       '...
       For Each file As String In files
           If IO.Path.GetFileName(file).StartsWith("~$") Then Continue For 'inserted line
           oWord = CreateObject("word.application")
           '...
   ```

Comment: I'd agree with this suggesstion if not then wrap it in a try catch temporarily and on the exception output some details about the file, such as name etc so we can try and help further.

Comment: Okay, I checked it and you are right, but 2nd option doesnt change anything.

Comment: @xeN – problem corrected. I replaced `file` with `IO.Path.GetFileName(file)` because each file is actually full path. Now `StartsWith()` will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, 2nd option doesn't work for me so i did it like this:

```
Sub Main()
    For Each arg As String In My.Application.CommandLineArgs
        Select Case Trim(LCase(arg))
            Case "/docx-pdf"
                Dim oWord As Word.Application
                Dim oDoc As Word.Document
                Dim path As String
                Console.WriteLine("Podaj scieżkę folderu:")
                path = Console.ReadLine()
                Dim afiles As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path + "\", "*.docx")
                Dim bfiles As String() = Directory.GetFiles(path + "\", "~$*")
                Dim cfiles = afiles.Except(bfiles)
                For Each file As String In cfiles
                    oWord = CreateObject("word.application")
                    oWord.Visible = False
                    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(file, ReadOnly:=True)
                    oDoc.SaveAs(FileName:=file.Replace(".docx", ".pdf"), FileFormat:=Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF)
                    oWord.Quit()
                Next
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Any other way to write it a bit shorter and cleaner?